# How do I calculate thrust for a high bypass turbofan engine? (7th grade)

Tags: electrical-engineering

so i'm a 7th grader trying to create something using a high bypass turbofan engine but I need to learn how to calculate the thrust for it and i'm unsure on how I am meant to do that. If anyone has any answers for me it would me much appreciated.

Comment: Also to add a note everything I have found is extremely complicated( I know its meant to be its physics) but I cant find anything meant to help seventh graders.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.